# How to find or search Issues With Attachments in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I want to find or search list of issues which have attachments.

Could someone please let me know how to search the same?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the JIRA Toolkit Plugin.

https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JTOOL/JIRA+Toolkit+Plugin

> Number of comments and attachments | You can now also display and search for the numbers of comments and attachments of an issue. You can also perform range searches on either of them.

Comment: I'm just a user and couldn't install the plugin. I would like to know how to do the search.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible without that (or any) plugin. BTW: Please edit your question and specify your JIRA version.

Comment: JIRA Version is v5.0.6. Assume the plugin has been installed. could you please let me know how to search?

Comment: i found that we can search for attach or attachment keyword since mostly people says attached or attachment when attaching the files.

Comment: Indirect way of searching for issues with Attachments: (comment ~ ATTACHED or comment ~ attachment) and component = "Test" order by updated -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Advanced Searching : https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching
2. Quick Search :   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+Quick+Search
3. Text Search :   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Performing+Text+Searches
4. User Guides:   https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA050/JIRA+User%27s+Guide

Comment: @kathir looks like you can also do `(attachments is not empty) order by updated`